# start third part application after VS application execution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I would like to start a third party application after execution completion from within VS2012.
The frame-work and application built in VS is SystemC based and outputs a value change dump (VCD). I would like the user of my sln/vcxproj to get a launch of GTKWave with trace.vcd as argument after F5 or Ctrl-F5 has completed (vcd file is closed).
To keep the project source files platform independent + user friendly I prefer a solution external to C++ language.

BR Daniel

Comment: Can't you have a system() call at the end of your main? Also it seems weird to me to want platform independence but require Visual Studio at the same time. Although some versions of Visual Studio work partially under linux with wine.

Comment: Now... that's just the thing isn't it ;) I'd hate to polute my git source code repo with platform/tool dependant code. The repo currently builds on linux, cygwin and VS with gcc or ms compilers. Makefiles and sln files portability was not what I was looking for.